# save data in variables of IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, service, intentservice

i have a `IntentService` that collect data from the user by intents.
i extract the integer numbers from the intent on: 
`protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){...}`
and save it in variables *out of this function*.

**the problem-**
when i finish `onHandleIntent()`
all my variables are initialize again 
and it seems like my service colese and start immidiately again.
(in the logCat i didn't see something wrong)

**the question-**
can i save data in variables at `Intentservice` or i can't?

please your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your IntentService terminated it is dereferenced and killed by the garbage collection (as far as I can judge that from your description). You could try to implement a receiver or save the variables in some kind of storage (SQLite, SharedPrefs, ...).

Compare the initial description of the IntentService: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: thank you very much on your detailed answer, but i success eventualy to find it in android site. 
i use `sharedPreferences` like you wrote :)